# why i can't add elements to the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing my homework, the teacher asked us to store student names and student grades out of 100. And should ask the users to enter the names and the grades. no error the code but when I run the file, it just asks me for the name for only once. But no problem like this with adding to the grade array? What could cause that to happen? What should be done to be able to enter names?

```
public class Assignment12 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int grade[] = new int[3];
    String name[] = new String[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter Student name");
      String studentName = input.nextLine();
      name[i] = studentName;

      System.out.println("Enter Student grade");
      int studentGrade = input.nextInt();
      grade[i] = studentGrade;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code below.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] marks = new int[3];
String[] names = new String[3];
//input marks
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        marks[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
//for Enter key character as input, in order to read the strings
scan.nextLine();
//loop to read names 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();
}
//for printing out marks
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(marks[i]);
}
//for printing out names
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```